# Linear Dependence of Stark Effect on Energy Level

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electric-fields

I'm trying to get intuitive understanding of the well-known Stark Effect in QM. Pauli has found that the splitting of the levels depends linearly on $n$, the principal quantum number of the hydrogen atom. Is there any intuitive explanation of this dependence?

Thanks,
Eran

Comment: I think you mean linear in the strength of the electric field not principal quantum number.

Comment: You have both. Please see page 8 here:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0212010v2.pdf